# Is there a Concise way to deal with PHP jagged associate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

If I have an array of arrays and want to display them in a table, is there an efficient way to display them?

e.g.

```
Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => 1234
        [upc] => 6-00000-01234-5
        [measure_amount] => 30 
        [strength] => 100 mg
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [sku] => 5432
        [upc] => 6-00000-05432-1
    )
)
```

I'd like to output a table of all products but if the key doesn't exist just display a blank item. Right now, the only way I can think of doing this is iterate through every item, get the array_keys, combine them into a master key list and then use the key list to generate a table, but I think it would make more sense to do this:

Convert the above to:

```
Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => 1234
        [upc] => 6-00000-01234-5
        [measure_amount] => 30 
        [strength] => 100 mg
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [sku] => 5432
        [upc] => 6-00000-05432-1
        [measure_amount] =>
        [strength] =>
    )
)
```

I'm sure there's a better approach to this, like as I iterate through the list of items, merge the array with a *model* associative array... but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: 1 your example won't work since both have a key of '0', the 2nd question needs to show that model array.

Comment: In order to create the second array, you'd need to do the iteration that you describe to get the master key list. So it doesn't really matter whether you do it when you're creating the table or when you're modifying the array.

Comment: Thanks @Forbs copy and paste typo.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I do the iteration to get the keys, but I'm wondering how I go about combining/creating that structure.... or should I bother creating a new array with empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [array_map](https://php.net/array-map) in combination with [array_merge](https://php.net/array-merge):

```
$data = [
  ['sku' => 1, 'upc' => 'foo', 'measure_amount' => 30, 'strength' => '100mg'],
  ['sku' => 2, 'upc' => 'bar'],
];

$clean = array_map(function ($entry) use ($complete_item) {
     $all_keys = array_keys($complete_item);
     $empty = array_combine($all_keys, array_fill(0, count($all_keys), ''));
     return array_merge($empty, $entry);
   },
   $data
);
```

This will output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["sku"]=>
    int(1)
    ["upc"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["measure_amount"]=>
    int(30)
    ["strength"]=>
    string(5) "100mg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["sku"]=>
    int(2)
    ["upc"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["measure_amount"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["strength"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done if you don't know the keys in advance? The keys will change as new attributes are added over time, so I wanted a flexible solution.

Comment: If you're able to pick the most complete object (ie, the one defining all keys), then yes, updating my reply

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...now your post makes sense, you have entries that have random fields but you wish to return an array with each element the same fields.  Here's the brute force way...I'm sure there is a function but I'm not sure..

```
$merge = array();
// Run the array for all the fields and put them in merge.
foreach($array1 as $val)
{
    $merge = array_merge($merge,$val);
}
// Now run merge to set to a default...This probably has a function I don't use
foreach($merge as $key=>$val)
{
    $merge[$key] = '';
}
// Now Use Merge to put it all back
foreach($array1 as $key=>$val)
{
      $array1[$key] = array_merge($merge,$val);
}
// Your array1 now contains rows with all the same elements and in the same order.
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is better for a large number of subarrays and/or large number of elements in subarrays, because it does not require additional memory for storing additional empty elements:

> Right now, the only way I can think of doing this is iterate through
>   every item, get the array_keys, combine them into a master key list
>   and then use the key list to generate a table.

Use this to collect all possible keys, if you don't know in advance what specific keys will be in the subarrays:

```
foreach ($mainArray as $subArray) {
   foreach ($subArray as $key=>$val) {
      if (!isset($allKeys[$key])) {
         $allKeys[$key] = '';
      }
   }
}
```

Then use inside loop `if (!isset($allKeys[$currentSubarrayKey]))` check to print empty table cell, because `isset` works much faster than `in_array`.

Comment: I do believe that if the data has the keys in different order, this results in the keys being added in a random order right?

Comment: Keys in `$allKeys` array will be in a random order.

Comment: In this case, not having the keys sorted isn't a deal breaker as I can always run them through a sort algo, but this is crazy concise code. I'm going to test it out.

Comment: Did you test my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the keys in the original array, I recommend creating a second array with the columns of the table you wish to create. Then you can loop through it like so:

```
$columns = array("sku","upc","measure_amount","strength");
foreach($mainArray as $a)
{
   foreach($columns as $col)
   {
      //Access the array element like this: $a[$col]
   }
}
```

Note: this only works if you know what the keys will be in advance.

Comment: Yeah... I can't guarantee that the keys won't change over time ad more attributes get added and subtracted.